# Sphere online judge ( Life, the Universe, and Everything )

Tags: c++, c, cppcheck

Your program is to use the brute-force approach in order to find the Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything. More precisely... rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers of one or two digits.

Input: 1 2 88 42 99

Output: 1 2 88

I tried to solve this programme with the help of c++ and end up getting wrong result.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,n;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cin>>n;
        if(n == 42)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then with the help of C I solved the problem and it came out like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (scanf("%d\n", &i) && i != 42)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

can you tell me what were my mistakes that i was making in the first programme. I am newbie to coding.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you are a "newbie to coding", then the best resource for you how to solve these kinds of simple problems [is a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Unfortunately, Stackoverflow is not a replacement for a C++ textbook. Meaningless online quiz sites only result in acquiring bad programming habits, like [bits/stdc++.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [using namespace std;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Please intend your code between the `{}`, like GaryNLOL did in his answer.

Comment: You should check if the return value of `scanf()` is 1 and not `EOF`. `scanf()` returns `EOF` in case of an error or end of file and `EOF` is true (Because it is not `0`).

Comment: The first program limits the input to 10 inputs. If `42` is the 12th input, that will be wrong anwser. Anyway, it does not output ***any*** answer at all.

Comment: Have a new array initialised. Put each element into the array until you reach 42 or end of inputs. Sort your new array and print it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It's a bad practice to use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` (More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)).
2. It's a bad practice to use `using namespace std;` (More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).
3. You aren't printing anything. Use `std::cout`.
4. For the readability of the code you should declare `i` in the `for` loop statement.
5. I agree with Sam Varshavchik. If you want to learn C++, search a good textbook instead of online quiz sites.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int n;
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
         std::cin >> n;
         if(n == 42)
            break;
         std::cout << n;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: To show best practice, I would also put `int n;` inside the body of the `for` loop